# A letter from 1872 in Kurrent

Tags: handwriting, kurrent

I noticed some of you are better at reading Sütterlin than I, who only learned it because in German high school math linear algebra class we wrote vector variables using Sütterlin letters. I did some writing but don't have enough experience. A Brazilian friend asked if I can help read. I can't. At the risk of getting dinged for being out of scope for questions here -- I have checked if deciphering is out of scope, but did not find it -- so I will ask.

[image]

My own reading is just a few words:

Trittau den 26 Juli 1872

Lieber Bruder

Jetz Ramne?? ich ander Rethe, ich bin
noch immer Gesied und Mineter...
...

it just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but 1872 predates Sütterlin, so it's probably some flavor ot Kurrent, a precursor (precursive?) of Sütterlin.

Comment: did you take the pic with a potatoe phone or has the imagehost compressed it? Higher Resolution would surely help a bit

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is indeed outside the scope of this page. It will not be helpful for any other visitor. It would be on topic to ask for single characters, perhaps and maybe, if it was an letter from Schiller to Goethe with a politicized debate, what a single word means.

Comment: @userunknown, wie ich sehe, kennen Sie doch diesen Meta-Post: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/sind-fragen-über-die-entschlüsselung-von-schriften-auch-handschriften-on-topic/1276#1276 ;-)

Comment: @userunknown, yes, please engage this subject on the referenced meta where the only accepted answer is that it is on topic. Thanks Björn to have found this link.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow: Diese Metafrage ist ein Duplikat, welches aus unerfindlichen Gründen nicht geschlossen wurde. Eine ältere Version mit meiner Argumentation findet sich [hier]{https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1478/266}. Hättest Du die Kommentare dort gelesen, wüsstest Du das. Antworten werden übrigens auf Meta ebenso akzeptiert wie hier: Völlig willkürlich, vom Fragesteller.

Answer (score 12):

As commented, this is German Kurrent font and hard to decipher due to the ink from the backside and the writer's style (*e.g.* only minute spaces between words, the curvature to mark the letter "u" is very pronounced and often looks like a separate letter, crossed out/corrected words, misspellings).

This is what I could decipher so far. I'll have another look later and try to fill the gaps.

---

Lieber Bruder
Jetz komme ich an die Reihe, ich bin
noch immer Gesund und Munter,
mir gehts gut und wohl. Ich habe die
Höhe von 5 Fuß erreicht welches mir
sehr freut, auch bin Ich mit vielen
R[] umgeben und ungefähr
75 ℔  schwer. Im Nächsten Brief werde
ich mein Bild hinschicken, und in diesem
Brief wirst Du Fritz Bild mit
Freuden in Empfang nehmen. Wir
haben jetzt einen neuen Lehrer wieder
namens Doose, dieser kann aber nicht
so viel als Herr Münster. Ich komme []
u[] 2 Jahre aus der Schule. Auch habe ich viele
Fische gefangen, []
gewölbte Bru[]tle. [] für die[ß|st]mal
will ich schließen, weil der Brief sonst
zuviel Geld kostet. Dein Bruder
Heinrich

Comment: Für "[] *namens Doose*" hätte ich eine Idee.

Comment: @vectory und welche?

Comment: *[wieder]*, aber der Rest sieht aus als Hätter der Schüler einen Schreibkrampf gehabt.

Comment: Ich verstehe, dass man gerne knobelt und anderen hilft, aber solche Anfragen bekommen wir zu hauf und immer finden sich ein paar, die nicht widerstehen können zu antworten. Macht das bitte per PN, wenn Ihr Lust habt, aber bringt nicht die Plattform dazu, solche Fragen anzuziehen. Der nächste mit e. ähnlichen Problem wird es mit Hilfe Eures Postings nicht können, sondern die Anfragen bleiben alle individuelle Servicewünsche ohne Lerneffekt. Voted stattdessen dafür, die Frage zu schließen, und beantwortet sie per PN, wenn es Euch juckt, und sprecht im Chat, wenn Ihr Publikum braucht, darüber.

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe bewußt die Schwierigkeiten mit diesem Text notiert, damit Nutzer mit ähnlichen Fragen mögliche Lösungsansätze finden, falls der eigene Text nicht/schwer anhand einer Alphabettabelle lesbar ist. Von daher sehe ich schon, dass man was lernen kann, so man denn möchte.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for making this an answer – if I had enough reputation to comment, I would rather write a comment on @Arsak's fine transcription, as (s)he did most of the work. Here's just building upon @Arsak's answer.
<strike>Deletions</strike> and insertions are < marked > as shown.
I have also added some remarks (below).

---

Lieber Bruder
Jetz komme ich an der Reihe, ich bin
noch immer Gesund und Munter,
mir gehts gut und wohl. Ich habe die
Höhe von 5 Fuß erreicht, welches mir
sehr freut, auch bin Ich mit vielen
Richten[?] umgeben, und ungefähr
[95|75] ℔ [= Pfund] schwer. < Im > Nächsten Brief werde
ich mein Bild hinschicken, und in diesem
Brief <strike>werdet Ihr</strike> wirst Du Fritz Bild mit
Freuden im Empfang nehmen. Wir
haben jetzt einen neuen Lehrer wieder
namens Doose, dieser kann aber nicht
so viel als Herr Münster. Ich komme[?]
um[?] 2 Jahre aus der Schule. Auch habe ich viele
Fische gefangen, denn es[?] wir[?] []
<strike>Br</strike> gewölbte Brüke < gebadet >. Für dießmal
will ich schließen, weil der Brief sonst
zuviel Geld kostet. Dein Bruder
Heinrich

---

The document was probably a collective letter from different family members, and seeing as Heinrich's letter is written on the *verso* page of a sheet, it might have been the last in the lot and at the very end of a *Bogen*. Hence his worry that writing an additional page would require another sheet and cost more to send.

The symbol on l. 8 ought to be a (pretty standard) abbreviation for [*Pfund*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfund#Historische_Masseeinheiten).
A *Pfund* in the German Reich was defined as weighing exactly 0.5 kg.
So the boy is five *Fuß* tall and weighs either 47.5 or 37.5 kg (95 or 75 *Pfund*).

The first word on l. 7 looks like "Richten" to me; I don't find it completely satisfactory, but here's a rationalization.
There is a documented  dialectal (esp. *niederdeutsch*) usage of *das Richt* or *die Richte* as equivalent to "Speise", "Gericht", "Mahlzeit" ([DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=richt)).
If the superimposed heading is correct ("Trittau den 26 Juli 1872"), the letter could have been written in a [town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trittau) in Schleswig-Holstein near Hamburg.
Thus, after stating his height, Heinrich would be saying "auch bin Ich mit vielen Richten umgeben", meaning he has plenty to eat; then he states his current weight.
Even then, a sentence such as "ich bin mit vielen Speisen umgeben" sounds clumsy to me; I can only speculate about it being a regional idiom, or standard back then, or peculiar to the writer.
(Other deviations from present-day grammar: "Jetz komme ich an **der** Reihe" and "welches **mir** sehr freut".)

I could not decipher certain words in the part about fishing and swimming near a "gewölbte Brüke" (l. 15-17); also, I am unsure about "komme" at the end of l. 14, as I don't see a typical, closed "o".

Comment: "[kmme] [im] [2.] Jahre aus der Schule". Wenn bei *kmme* schon das o fehlt, kann auch bei *im* falsch mit u angefangen worden sein. Man sieht schon am unteren Ende der Zwei, das Bild wurde mit Kantenglättung oder anderen Filtern bearbeitet, wobei ein kleiner Punkt wohl draufgegangen sein könnte. Vermute, das bedeutet vorrübergehenden Urlaub, nicht den Schulabschluss.

Comment: Ich verstehe, dass man gerne knobelt und anderen hilft, aber solche Anfragen bekommen wir zu hauf und immer finden sich ein paar, die nicht widerstehen können zu antworten. Macht das bitte per PN, wenn Ihr Lust habt, aber bringt nicht die Plattform dazu, solche Fragen anzuziehen. Der nächste mit e. ähnlichen Problem wird es mit Hilfe Eures Postings nicht können, sondern die Anfragen bleiben alle individuelle Servicewünsche ohne Lerneffekt. Voted stattdessen dafür, die Frage zu schließen, und beantwortet sie per PN, wenn es Euch juckt, und sprecht im Chat, wenn Ihr Publikum braucht, darüber.

Comment: Wow! I wish I could upvote your answer twice. You have so much detail and explication of the oddities like "Richten". I hope some more people will upvote your answer to help you out with some more points so you can start commenting. Thanks!

Comment: @userunknown, there is a huge Lerneffekt. You know that bytes on a website are cheap.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow: Yes, I know. Du weißt auch, dass die Leute weniger auf das achten, was in Regelwerken steht (die keiner liest), als darauf, was die anderen machen (Gehwegradler, Falschparker)? Und Zeit ist nicht billiig und es ist nicht billig ein paar Dutzend Leute zu finden, die einem helfen wollen. Wieso machen wir hier nicht auch ebay-Kleinanzeigen Konkurrenz und verkloppen unseren Kellerinhalt? Platz ist billig - ein, zwei Kleinanzeigen am Tag - wen kann das groß stören?

Comment: @userunknown, ebay? That's a strawman argument. Nobody does Kleinanzeigen here. Get a life.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and @GuntherSchadow, thanks for your kind words! I also think that there can be a Lerneffekt, provided a user is willing to engage with the text (as opposed to just "getting a transcription done"). Learning to read Kurrent isn't just about downloading a "table of Sütterlinglyphs", and a moderately challenging example like this one can be quite useful.

Comment: @userunknown We have a policy to accept this kind of questions. If you intent to change this policy, please discuss this at meta: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/sind-fragen-%c3%bcber-die-entschl%c3%bcsselung-von-schriften-auch-handschriften-on-topic/1276? and not here.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Bitte lies dazu meinen Hinweis oben, bei der Frage, Die Frage wurde bereits 4 Jahre früher von mehr Personen diskutiert. Meinem Wunsch auf Schließung der 2. Frage als Duplicat ist leider nicht entsprochen worden.

Comment: @userunknown Auch in dem anderen Thread ist eine klare Mehrheit dafür zu erkennen, diese Fragen als on-topic zu betrachten. Wenn du eine Policy ändern willst, mach das bitte auf meta, und entfache die bereits geführte Diskussion nicht unter dem Artikel neu. Dafür ist meta gemacht.

Comment: @userunknown " solche Anfragen bekommen wir zu hauf" - ich habe zum tag *handwriting* genau 55 Fragen gefunden, davon ca. 10 mit allgemeinen Themen. Also ca, 45 Bitten um Entzifferung sei Start von german.stackexchange.  Das ist nun wirklich nicht viel.

Comment: @KritikerderElche: Wenn Du die Tags nach Häufigkeit sortierst, dann findest Du "Handwriting" im obersten Viertel liegt. Nach erst 7 Monaten mag es Dir noch nicht so vorkommen.

Comment: @userunknown Formal gesehen hast Du Recht, der tag "handwriting" steht auf Seite 3 von 12 (https://german.stackexchange.com/tags?page=3&tab=popular).  Allerdings gibt es von insg. 14.931 Fragen nur 56 zu diesem tag (wobei wie gesagt ca. 10 nichts mit Entzifferung zu tun haben). Also nur etwas mehr als 0,3 %. Es gibt übrigens zahlreiche tags mit 0 Fragen (beginnend auf Seite 8), man sollte sich überlegen, ob die wirklich gebraucht werden. Ist aber eine völlig andere Baustelle ...